# Python - Find value anywhere within JSON and return location

Tags: python, json, dictionary

In Python I'm currently working with a very large JSON file with some deep dictionaries and arrays. I'm having an issue where it's not constant. For example that's below, it's essentially countries, with regions/states, cities, and suburbs. The issue is that if there is only one suburb, it'll return a dictionary, though if there's more than one, it's a array with a dictionary making me have to add another line of code to go deeper. Sure, can ifelse/for it, but this is only a very small portion of the inconstancy and it's just not proper going ifelse all the time.

What I'd like to do is simply search anything within **Belgium** for the dictionary entry `"code": "8400"` and return it's location within the JSON file. What would be my best approach in order to do something like this? Thanks!

```
***SNIP***    
{
        "code": "BE", 
        "name": "Belgium", 
        "regions": {
            "region": [
                {
                    "code": "45", 
                    "name": "Flanders", 
                    "places": {
                        "place": [
                            {
                                "code": "1790", 
                                "name": "Affligem"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "code": "8570", 
                                "name": "Anzegem"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "code": "8630", 
                                "name": "Diksmuide"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "code": "9600", 
                                "name": "Ronse"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "subregions": {
                        "subregion": [
                            {
                                "code": "46", 
                                "name": "Coast", 
                                "places": {
                                    "place": [
                                        {
                                            "code": "8300", 
                                            "name": "Knokke-Heist"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8400", 
                                            "name": "Oostende", 
                                            "subplaces": {
                                                "subplace": {
                                                    "code": "8450", 
                                                    "name": "Bredene"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8420", 
                                            "name": "De Haan"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8430", 
                                            "name": "Middelkerke"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8434", 
                                            "name": "Westende-Bad"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8490", 
                                            "name": "Jabbeke"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8660", 
                                            "name": "De Panne"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8670", 
                                            "name": "Oostduinkerke"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "code": "47", 
                                "name": "Cities", 
                                "places": {
                                    "place": [
                                        {
                                            "code": "1000", 
                                            "name": "Brussels"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "2000", 
                                            "name": "Antwerp"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8000", 
                                            "name": "Bruges"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8340", 
                                            "name": "Damme"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "9000", 
                                            "name": "Gent"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "code": "48", 
                                "name": "Interior", 
                                "places": {
                                    "place": [
                                        {
                                            "code": "2260", 
                                            "name": "Westerlo"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "2400", 
                                            "name": "Mol"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "2590", 
                                            "name": "Berlaar"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8500", 
                                            "name": "Kortrijk", 
                                            "subplaces": {
                                                "subplace": {
                                                    "code": "8940", 
                                                    "name": "Wervik"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8610", 
                                            "name": "Handzame"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8755", 
                                            "name": "Ruiselede"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8900", 
                                            "name": "Ieper"
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "code": "8970", 
                                            "name": "Poperinge"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
```

**EDIT:**

I was asked to show how I'm currently getting through this JSON file. Root is a dictionary containing numbers that equal the city/suburb I'm trying to search for. It doesn't define whether it is a city or suburb before hand. Below is my lazyly coded search while I was trying to learn how to dig through this JSON file, until I realized how complicated it was getting and got a bit stuck.
**SNIP**

```
for k in dataDict['countries']['country']:
    if k['code'] == root['country']:
        for y in k['regions']['region']['places']['place']:
            if y['code'] == root['place']:
                city = y['name']
            else:
                try:
                    for p in y['subplaces']['subplace']:
                        if p['code'] == root['place']:
                            city = p['name']
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: Can you show your search function? Is your search function recursive?

Comment: By "location" do you mean the associated name, or some sort of path to the element within the JSON text?

Comment: @jorispilot I added how I'm searching at the moment.

Comment: @RusselBorogove Either, but preferably the path to the element so I can apply the same code to later functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, each dictionary has the following structure:

```
{"code": # some int
 "name": # some str
  none / "country" / "place" / whatever # some dict or list
```

You can write a recursive function that handle one and only one dict:

```
def foo(my_dict):
    if my_dict['code'] == root['place']:
        city = my_dict['name']
    elif "country" in my_dict:
        city = foo(my_dict['country'])
    elif "place" in my_dict:
        # 
        # and so on...
    else:
        city = None
    return city
```

Hope this example will help you.